# -webkit-app-region: drag is not dragging frameless window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I am setting property -webkit-app-region: drag to title bar onmouseover event and removing the property onmouseout event. Setting the property dynamically not making framless window draggable.

if drag property is added to titlebar through class or as inline property, then drag functionality is working fine.

```
 .titlebar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 32px;
    background-color: #B2E4BD;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
}
```

But i want to have the drag functionality to titlebar only when mouse is over titlebar and when mouse is moved out of titlebar then drag property should be removed from titlebar.

```
$('.titlebar').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('.titlebar').css('-webkit-app-region', 'drag');
});

$('.titlebar').on('mouseout', function(){
    $('.titlebar').css('-webkit-app-region', 'no-drag');
});
```

Comment: This looks like a bugreport for https://crbug.com, not a question for stackoverflow (which requires the code and a description of an attempt to fix the problem).

Comment: Please post your code, seeing the real thing is always more helpful than reading a description. Also please specify if this is for a Chrome extension or app.